# How to quit an autogenerated horizontal scrollbar on asp:Gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm generating an asp:GridView that shows on its own a horizontal scrollbar that has no purpose, it can be seen here (http://s2.subirimagenes.com/otros/previo/thump_9255980horizontalscrollbar.jpg), it's what displays on the bottom of the image.

I'd like to know how can I disable it, shouldn't be too difficult but I cannot find a way to do it.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: The GridView is a table, and tables did not have scrollbars, so see your code, where you have place this gridview (on iframe, on div ?), there you must change the style